# How to accurately access weather API via the $.getjson method JSON

Tags: jquery, api, getjson

I'm building a weather app on FCC and I'm stuck because my code is not working.  I'm not getting a pop up request for browser access to my location. 
I wrapped that pop-up request in my `button.click` function. 
I'm a novice and I'm getting very frustrated. I need help!!

Here is my Code:

```
      var Api= "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?";

        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("button").click(function(){

        if (navigator.geolocation) {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            
         var lat = "lat=" + position.coords.latitude ;
            
         var lon = "lon=" + position.coords.longitude;

   $.get(Api+lat+"&"+ lon, function(result){

        $("#city").text(result.main.name);

        $("#country").text(result.sys.country);

        $("#weather").text(result.weather[0].main);

        $("#w-icon").text(result.weather[0].icon);

        $("#temp").text(result.main.temp);

        $("humidity").text(result.main.humidity);

        });


        });


        });
            else {

        console.log ("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
    }
         });
```

https://codepen.io/Ojomiba/pen/dVgQeQ

Comment: Why the down vote. I'll get banned from asking further questions when I'm trying to use the site to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the developer tools in your browser.

Look at the Console.

**Read the error messages**.

---

> Uncaught ReferenceError: lat is not defined

You've defined `lat` inside the function you pass to `getCurrentPosition`, but you are trying to use it **outside** that function.

You need to move the code that tries to use it so it is inside the function.